# Deserialize xml Elements with same Attributes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd

I am deserializing a xml file with an attribute and a xml text. The problem is that those elements have the same attributes. So I am always getting the error that I must not have two identical TypeNames in XmlType.

My xml:

```
<group_id xsi:type="xsd:int">1</group_id>
<name xsi:type="xsd:int">myNameView</name>
```

And my C#:

```
       [XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", TypeName = "int")]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "group_id")]
public class Group_id
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", TypeName = "int")]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "name")]
public class Name
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is the TypeName in XmlType Attribute. If I name only one element with a TypeName it is correctly deserialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` handles types for you, based on the `xsi:type` attribute. By trying to handle these yourself, you're causing it some grief.

If you declare your elements as `object`, then the serializer will use the type attributes to determine how to deserialize the values. Note as your example is just a fragment, I've assumed root element called `root`:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement("group_id")]
    public object GroupId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public object Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now when you deserialize your example, you'd actually get an exception (as `myNameView` isn't an integer).  You can fix by either changing the type to `xsd:string` or changing the value to a valid integer.

In the event the XML was valid, you'd see that the types deserialized map directly to the type attributes.  See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2K8sSN) for a working demo.